# auto mute a member if they say a specific word discord py rewrite

Tags: events, discord, discord.py, mute

```
import discord
import re
from itertools import cycle


class Status(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
```

```
 @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.id == self.client.user.id:
            return
        if re.search("\.\.\.", ctx.content):
            await ctx.send("you're... gonna get... muted... if you.. talk... like.. this...")
            user = ctx.message.author
            # print(str(user))
            # print(str(message.content))
            muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            await self.client.add_roles(ctx.author, muted_role)
```

What I want is to temporarily mute a user if they use ellipses in a message they send. `ctx.send` doesn't work, the bot does not send a message to the channel. It says that `self.client.add_roles` doesn't exist.

`Muted` is a role that I have created that does not have any send message permissions.

Any idea why? Some help would be hugely appreciated. I'm using

`AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send'` this is the error I get

[EDIT]

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    # @commands.command()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id == self.client.user.id:
            return
        if re.search("\.\.\.", message.content):
            await message.channel.send("you're... gonna get... muted... if you.. talk... like.. this...")
            user = message.author
            muted_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            await user.add_roles(muted_role, reason="you know what you did", atomic=True)
```

I took a look at the documentation and did this, it works, thank you for the support :)

Comment: change the last line to `await self.user.add_roles(muted_role)`

Comment: is it working fine now?

Comment: yes it works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many mistakes, please have a look at the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

I have correct them for you -

```
 @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.id == self.client.user.id:
            return
        else:
            await message.channel.send("you're... gonna get... muted... if you.. talk... like.. this...")
            user = message.author
            print(str(user))
            print(str(message.content))
            muted_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            await self.user.add_roles(muted_role)
```

Let me know if you do still get any errors.

**Last edit-**

I tried this command for myself outside a cog, and it works perfectly fine :)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == client.user.id:
        return
    elif "test" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("you're... gonna get... muted... if you.. talk... like.. this...")
        user = message.author
        print(str(user))
        print(str(message.content))
        muted_role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Muted")
        await user.add_roles(muted_role)
    else:
        return
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: try using `await self.user.add_roles(muted_role)`

Comment: ```AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'user'``` this happens

Comment: try removing `self` maybe?